# Use WebDeploy from VS2010 to execute CMD on web server

Tags: asp.net, web-deployment

I want to execute some batch files on the web server (I have control over it's IIS) before and after the deployment operation from my VS2010.

I've added a "runCommand" provider on my server's IIS, and added this code to the .csproj file:

```
<Target Name="AddingCMDtoManifest">
  <Message Text="Adding CMD to Manifest" />
  <ItemGroup>
    <MsDeploySourceManifest Include="runCommand">
      <path>C:\blahblah.bat</path>
    </MsDeploySourceManifest>
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

but nothing seems to change, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to execute your target in the right phase. I've done the following thing and it works.

```
<PropertyGroup >
    <RunCommandPath>DeploySettings\NightlyBuild.RunCommand.cmd</RunCommandPath>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="SetupCustomManifestProviders" BeforeTargets="AddContentPathToSourceManifest">
    <ItemGroup>
      <MsDeploySourceManifest Include="runCommand">
        <Path>$(RunCommandPath)</Path>
        <dontUseCommandExe>true</dontUseCommandExe>
        <waitInterval>10000</waitInterval>
        <AdditionalProviderSettings>dontUseCommandExe;waitInterval</AdditionalProviderSettings>
      </MsDeploySourceManifest>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```